# Differentiability of $ f(x,y)=\frac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R $ be defined by
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
       f(x,y)=\dfrac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}\ \ \ &(x,y)\ne(0,0)   \\
      0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \\
   \end{cases}
$$

Let $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ denote the first order partial derivative of $f(x,y)$  with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively,at the point $(0,0)$. The which one of the following statements is TRUE?

$(A)$ $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ but $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ do not exist.

$(B)$ $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

$(C)$ $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

$(D)$ $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ but $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist.

My attempt:

I was **checking continuity** so:

Choosing path $y=mx$

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{2x^3+3m^3x^3}{x^2+m^2x^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{2x^3+3m^3x^3}{x^2+m^2x^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{x(2+3m^3)}{1+m^2}=0$

$f(0,0)=0=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Makes it continuous so option $D$ cancels out

**Checking partial differentiability:**

$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)\cdot(6x^2)-(2x^3+3y^3) \cdot (4x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Choosing path $y=mx$

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{(x^2+m^2x^2)\cdot(6x^2)-(2x^3+3m^3x^3) \cdot (4x)}{(x^2+m^2x^2)^2}$

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{(1+m^2)\cdot(6)-(2+3m^3) \cdot (4)}{(1+m^2)^2}$

For different values of $m$ we will have different answers so the limit is not unique.

$A$ option cancels out

So a function to be differentiable it must satisfy the following:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)}=\dfrac{f((0+h),(0+k))-f(x,y)-h \cdot f_x(0,0)-k \cdot f_y(0,0)))}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

but $f_x$ and $f_y$ doesn't exist so its not differentiable.

Am I thinking it right so only option left is $C$

Comment: Showing the $y=mx$ limits go to $0$ does not prove the limit exists. This limit does exist, but you'll have to use squeeze theorem to show it. Also, a function can be differentiable at a point but not continuous, so your second work doesn't show the function is not differentiable, either.

Comment: @NinadMunshi partial derivatives don't exist that's what I have used to say it is not differentiable.

Comment: @NinadMunshi for any value of $m$ limits will be zero that's what I have used to say about the continuity of this function.

Comment: The partial derivatives do exist, they are $2$, and $3$, respectively. You have to compute them from definition. And just because the limit along every straight line goes to $0$, does not mean the limit exists. As a counterexample, try finding the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi $3xy$ partial derivative with respect to $x$ will be  $3y$ .Definition will give same results isnt?

Comment: @NinadMunshi edited

Comment: But do you understand my point that $y=mx$ can never prove a limit exists?

Comment: @NinadMunshi

$\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$ 

Taking $y=mx$

$\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{mx^3}{x^4+m^2x^2}=\frac{mx^2}{x^2+m^2}$ 

$2$nd step is taking $y=x$

$\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{x^3}{x^4+x^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}=0$ .

I am not sure $\frac{mx^2}{x^2+m^2}$ will always be zero. What should I learn from it ?

Comment: What happens if you take the path $y=x^2$ ?

Comment: $\dfrac{x^4}{x^4+x^4}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi One time it comes zero and one time it is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ implies limit is not unique thus don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part we have that

$$\frac{|2x^3+3y^3|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{2|x^3|}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{3|y^3|}{x^2+y^2} \leq 2|x|+3|y|$$

thus the limit goes to $0$ by squeeze theorem and the function is continuous. For differentiability we must compute the partials at $(0,0)$ by definition:

$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x-0}{x} = 2$$

and similarly $f_y(0,0) = 3$. Therefore we need to check whether the following limit exists and equals $0$:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to0} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-2x-3y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I'll leave this last step for you to check.

Comment: Starting discussion here....I am following this [professor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP2KnIj1yXU&ab_channel=Dr.GajendraPurohit) and all the method he has taught are based on $y=mx$. I don't understand what should follow in general in all questions. For exam point of you if I will go via definition it will consume my time. Could you please guide me here?

Comment: Now when you are using the definition for calculating derivative we can simply do this cant we?

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2+y^2} $

$f(x,0)=\dfrac{2x^3+0}{x^2+0}=2x$

and

$f'(x,0)=f_x(0,0)=2$ ?

When can this method go wrong ?

Comment: First of all, the professor in the video tells you to do the partial derivative by definition. Second, the professor in the video is wrong to say $y=mx$ limit tells you anything. Did you, or did you not look at the counterexample I gave in my previous comment? If you don't try that limit, why should I spend any more time helping you?

Comment: Regarding partial derivative, I have told you I am saving time. Could you correct me there? I understood the part of continuity that I shouldn't follow $y=mx$ I was just telling you I followed him.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your questions, if you are asking any. It looks like you are only repeating the techniques I'm suggesting, which is fine, but again there is no question to be had.

Comment: Its fine thanks